# UFC dataset InvalidArgumentError assertion failed: [Label IDs must < n_classes] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:]

Tags: python, tensorflow-estimator

```
pandas, tensorflow and numpy are imported here

****Download UFC dataset from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data

INPUT_PATH = "./breast-cancer-wisconsin.data"
OUTPUT_PATH = "./breast-cancer-wisconsin.csv"

Headers = ["CodeNumber", "ClumpThickness", "UniformityCellSize", 
            "UniformityCellShape", "MarginalAdhesion", 
            SingleEpithelialCellSize", "BareNuclei", "BlandChromatin", 
            "NormalNucleoli", "Mitoses", "CancerType"]
```

** Handling missing information, i.e., replacing "?" with NAN values and dropping those columns

```py
def handle_missings(dataset, missing_vals, drop_cols = []):  
    dataset.replace(missing_vals, np.NaN, inplace=True)  
    dataset.dropna(inplace=True)  
    dataset.drop(drop_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)  
    return dataset

def data_file_to_csv():  # conversion of data file to csv

    dataframe = pd.read_csv(INPUT_PATH, names = headers)  
    dataframe.to_csv(OUTPUT_PATH, index=False)     # this saves dataframe in a csv file

def train_input_fn(df):  # Tensorflow estimator input function read 
from the pandas dataframe

    (x = df[feature_headers], y = df[target_label])

def main():    -- main function 
    data_file_to_csv()   
    dataset = pd.read_csv(OUTPUT_PATH)   
    dataset = handle_missings(dataset, '?', Headers[6])   # replace quoted characters with NaN and then remove the rows 

    feature_headers = Headers[1:-1]  
    target_label = Headers[-1]  

    dataset['BareNuclei'] =  dataset['BareNuclei'].astype(np.int64)#.size())#str.find("?"))
    #print ("missing count ", dataset.dtypes.value_counts())

    feat_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in 
                                           feature_headers]    

    model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feat_columns,  
                             model_dir = None, n_classes=2)  

    model.train(input_fn=train_input_fn(dataset), steps=100)
```

error while running above code with InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed: [Label IDs must < n_classes] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:]

Comment: Please provide some context of what you are trying to do, your system, etc. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, I'm learning tensorflow estimator API, so, as a first step tried to use premade estimator for classification tasks on breast cancer dataset from UFC but ended up with the error with the above code. The error is Invalid Argument Error

Comment: InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Label IDs must < n_classes] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:] [x (dnn/head/ToFloat:0) = ] [[2][4][4]...] [y (dnn/head/assert_range/Const:0) = ] [2]
  [[Node: dnn/head/assert_range/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT], summarize=3,